# emoji overflows out of text widget

Tags: flutter, emoji

I am trying to display emoji on screen but it is not working as it should.

Because emoji's size is so small by default, to make it look bigger I'm increasing its font size. It works fine till fontsize of 68,but when I set it to 69 it overflows out of text widget.
behaviour of emoji

on font size 68

[image: 68]

vs on font size 69

[image: 69]

why is it happening? Is there any alternative to increasing the size of emoji without using fontsize?.

```dart
InkWell(
      child: Text(
        "\ud83d\ude1c",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        textScaleFactor: ScaleSize.textScaleFactor(context),
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize:68,
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: can try removing `textScaleFactor`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh nope! not working

Comment: Can you test this on separate project,